# How can I set an individual prop value on a component that is called 5 times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am calling a component 5 times. Like, it is called 4 times on its first parent component but then I need to called that parent component on another grandfather component which holds the value I am going to need.

This is the child comp:

```
// imports

const PassengerAvatar = ({ numberOfPassengers, cardinalPoint }) => (
  <Svg.G>
    <Svg.Text>
      <Svg.TSpan>
        {numberOfPassengers}
      </Svg.TSpan>

      <Svg.TSpan>
        {cardinalPoint}
      </Svg.TSpan>
    </Svg.Text>
  </Svg.G>
);

export default PassengerAvatar;
```

Its parent where it gets call 4 times:

```
// imports

const PassengersCircle = ({ numberOfPassengers }) => (

      <View>
        <PassengerAvatar
          numberOfPassengers={numberOfPassengers}
          cardinalPoint="NORTH"
        />

        <PassengerAvatar
          numberOfPassengers={numberOfPassengers}
          cardinalPoint="SOUTH"
        />

        <PassengerAvatar
          numberOfPassengers={numberOfPassengers}
          cardinalPoint="EAST"
        />

        <PassengerAvatar
          numberOfPassengers={numberOfPassengers}
          cardinalPoint="WEST"
        />
      </View>

)

// export
```

Grandfather component:
On the grandfather component I make a fetch of an API data:

```
// imports

import { has, countBy, property } from 'lodash';

import tabViewStyles from './styles/TabViewStyles';
import PassengersCircle from './PassengersCircle';
import AllPassengersList from './AllPassengersList';
import { unassignedDropOffPassengersAction } from './actions/homeScreen';

let passengersGoingNorth;
let passengersGoingSouth;
let passengersGoingWest;
let passengersGoingEast;

class AllPassengersDropOff extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDropOffPassengers();
    this.callFilter();
  }

  fetchDropOffPassengers = async () => {
    const { unassignedDropOffPassengersActionHandler, userToken } = this.props;
    if (userToken) {
      // here I perform the fetch
     // and save the the data here: unassignedDropOffPassengers
    }
  };

  callFilter = () => {
    // here I could set a filter to get every cardinal point separately 
    const { unassignedDropOffPassengers } = this.props;
    ({
      N: passengersGoingNorth,
      S: passengersGoingSouth,
      W: passengersGoingWest,
      E: passengersGoingEast,
    } = countBy(unassignedDropOffPassengers, property('cardinalpoint')));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
          <PassengersCircle
            numberOfPassengers={//numberOfPassengers based on cardinal point}
          />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

// export
```

As you see, in the father component there is a prop `cardinalPoint`.
This is how the array looks:

```
[{
  "id": 8,
  "phone": "45379911",
  "pickup": 1,
  "cardinalpoint": "S",
},
{
  "id": 10,
  "phone": "234482933",
  "pickup": 1,
  "cardinalpoint": "N",
}]
```

On `numberOfPassengers`, what I need is to do something like: If there are `10` passengers going to North, then set that number on the number of passengers of the appropriate component call. Like here:

```
        <PassengerAvatar
          numberOfPassengers={numberOfPassengers}
          cardinalPoint="NORTH"
        />
```

So that is the main idea.
As you saw above, in the grandfather component I call the father component like this:

```
          <PassengersCircle
            numberOfPassengers={//numberOfPassengers based on cardinal point}
          />
```

So, on the prop `numberOfPassengers` I could do something like
`numberOfPassengers={ifPassengerNorth ? northPassengers : ... }`

So what can I do to accomplish what I need, what am I missing?

Comment: Can't you just eliminate the father component and have the grandfather call the four directions itself?

Comment: Hi @JasonPelletier not actually. I posted that piece of code on the father component just to simplify my post.

Comment: You could pass an object with the number of passengers and their direction to PassengersCircle. Then just output them for each avatar